# What are these explicit "forall"s doing?

Tags: haskell, higher-rank-types, forall

What is the purpose of the `forall`s in this code?

```
class  Monad m  where
    (>>=)       :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    (>>)        :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
        -- Explicit for-alls so that we know what order to
        -- give type arguments when desugaring
```

(some code omitted).  This is from the code for [Monads](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#Monad).

---

My background:  I don't really understand `forall` or when Haskell has them implicitly.

Also, and it may not be significant, but GHCi allows me to omit the `forall` when giving `>>` a type:

```
Prelude> :t (>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
  :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b -> m b
```

(no error).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of Rank2Types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types)

Comment: @sacundim disagree; the question is not about what `forall` does in general, or what higher rank types are.  The question is about what, specifically, `forall` is doing in this code, in light of the comment that follows it.

Comment: This is an example of ExplicitForall.  They're not higher ranked types, and removing the foralls wouldn't change the type.  I'm not precisely sure why they are an advantage here.  The comment suggests that it aids the compiler in the desugaring phase.

Comment: [Matt S](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1683055/matt-s) is right, those are exactly the foralls that the language implicitly specifies, so semantically, their absence or presence doesn't change anything. I have however no idea what use the compiler could make of their presence in the desugaring phase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My background: I don't really understand forall or when Haskell has them implicitly.

Okay, consider the type of `id`, `a -> a`. What does `a` mean, and where does it come from? When you define a value, you can't just use arbitrary variables that aren't defined anywhere. You need a top-level definition, or a function argument, or a `where` clause, &c. In general, if you use a variable, [it must be bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) somewhere.

The same is true of type variables, and `forall` is one such way to bind a type variable. Anywhere you see a type variable that isn't explicitly bound (for example, `class Foo a where ...` binds `a` inside the class definition), it's implicitly bound by a `forall`.

So, the type of `id` is implicitly `forall a. a -> a`. What does this mean? Pretty much what it says. We can get a type `a -> a` *for all* possible types `a`, or from another perspective, if you pick any specific type you can get a type representing "functions from your chosen type to itself". The latter phrasing should sound a bit like defining a function, and as such you can think of `forall` as being similar to a lambda abstraction for types.

GHC uses various intermediate representations during compilation, and one of the transformations it applies is making the similarity to functions more direct: implicit `forall`s are made explicit, and anywhere a polymorphic value is used for a specific type, it is first *applied to a type argument*.

We can even write both `forall`s and lambdas as one expression. I'll abuse notation for a moment and replace `forall a.` with `/\a =>` for visual consistency. In this style, we can define `id = /\a => \(x::a) -> (x::a)` or something similar. So, an expression like `id True` in your code would end up translated to something like `id Bool True` instead; just `id True` would no longer even make sense.

Just as you can reorder function arguments, you can likewise reorder the type arguments, subject only to the (rather obvious) restriction that type arguments must come before any value arguments of that type. Since implicit `forall`s are always the outermost layer, GHC could potentially choose any order it wanted when making them explicit. Under normal circumstances, this obviously doesn't matter.

I'm not sure *exactly* what's going on in this case, but based on the comments I would guess that the conversion to using explicit type arguments and the desugaring of `do` notation are, in some sense, not aware of each other, and therefore the order of type arguments is specified explicitly to ensure consistency. After all, if something is blindly applying two type arguments to an expression, it matters a great deal whether that expression's type is `forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b` or `forall b a. m a -> m b -> m b`!