# Applying Function Passed as Argument to Different Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parametric-polymorphism

Is there any way to apply a function passed as an argument to two different types? As a contrived example, I can create a `(Maybe Int, Maybe Bool)` with the expression `(Just 3, Just True)`, but if I try to make this behaviour more generic with the function

```
generic :: (a -> Maybe a) -> (Maybe Int, Maybe Bool)
generic f = (f 3, f True)
```

so that I might be able to do something like `generic Just`, the compiler complains because the type variable `a` is constant.

The use case of this is applying a generic function to a tree structure where each node is parametrized by a type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved using rank-2 polymorphism as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
generic :: (forall a. a -> Maybe a) -> (Maybe Int, Maybe Bool)
generic f = (f 3, f True)
```

Often you will need some typeclass restriction (not because the implementation of `generic` demands it, but because the caller cannot pass an argument that works for all types), e.g.

```
genericNum :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a) -> (Int, Integer)
genericNum f = (f 3, f 9)
```

Comment: I don't know how you feel about it, but I *always* turn on `ScopedTypeVariables` when I use an extension that enables `forall`; otherwise I'm likely to get confused down the road.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Do you know of any good resources that go through all these modern language extensions? All of the Haskell books I can find deal mostly with Haskell 98, and Haskell documentation can be pretty exhausting...

Comment: @igorbark If you want all the extensions, there is no better source than [the horse's mouth](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghc-language-features.html).

Comment: @igorbark: A few people seem to have gotten use of [my explanation of `RankNTypes` over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types/12033549#12033549).