# Which design pattern is this? printPersonsOlderThan

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, decoupling

I read a lot about design patterns but I still have difficulty identifying when I have to use them. Today I was reading oracle documentation about lambdas and saw a class "evolution" and said "Hey, clearly there's some decoupling here". I think there's a well known pattern here but don't know exactly which is.

Another question that I also have about this is, if I'm not using SPRING where the folders structure about interfaces and implementations is very clear, which would be -according goog practices- the project structure where I must create the interfaces.

The example started with this code:

```
public static void printPersonsOlderThan(List<Person> roster, int age) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (p.getAge() >= age) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

Then continued with this:

```
public static void printPersonsWithinAgeRange(
    List<Person> roster, int low, int high) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (low <= p.getAge() && p.getAge() < high) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

And ended with this:

```
public static void printPersons(
    List<Person> roster, CheckPerson tester) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

Created this interface:

```
interface CheckPerson {
    boolean test(Person p);
}
```

And this was the implementation:

```
class CheckPersonEligibleForSelectiveService implements CheckPerson {
    public boolean test(Person p) {
        return p.gender == Person.Sex.MALE &&
            p.getAge() >= 18 &&
            p.getAge() <= 25;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Do you see a design pattern here? If yes... wich one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have implemented a [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) like a Java FileFilter, this is close to the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

[Could someone in simple terms explain to me the visitor pattern's purpose with examples if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604169/could-someone-in-simple-terms-explain-to-me-the-visitor-patterns-purpose-with-e)

Answer (score 1):

I passed Design Pattern subject at University with highest grade, still I can't seem to identify any familiar pattern.

Most likely, no predefined patterns are used, but the `CheckPerson` has been abstracted for obvious reasons.

At University, we group classes in packages, and Interfaces are usually placed in the same package with implementing classes.

Comment: Don't you agree with stacker about the visitor pattern? I think hes' right.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! I looked into the visitor pattern example and must admit that it looks auspiciously similar.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Visitor, you can consider to use [Strategy](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Strategy/) pattern.

```
public abstract class PrintStrategy {

    abstract protected List<Person> checkPerson(List<Person> list);

    public void printPerson(List<Person> roster){

        List<Person> filteredRoster = this.checkPerson(roster);
        for (Person person : filteredRoster) {
            person.print();
        }
    }
}

public class PrintOlderThanStartegy extends PrintStrategy {

    private final int ageWaterMark;

    public PrintOlderThanStartegy(final int ageWaterMark){
        this.ageWaterMark = ageWaterMark;
    }

    protected List<Person> checkPerson(List<Person> roster) {

        List<Person> filteredRoster = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (Person person : roster) {
            if(person.getAge() > ageWaterMark){
                filteredRoster.add(person);
            }
        }
        return filteredRoster;
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> roster = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setAge(50);
        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setAge(20);

        roster.add(p1);
        roster.add(p2);

        PrintStrategy printStrategy = new PrintOlderThanStartegy(30);
        printStrategy.printPerson(roster);
    }

}
```